# Html page shows up locally but not when published on the server

Tags: html, vb.net, streamwriter

I am creating html code as a string (named htmlString) in a Visual Basic .Net program and want to show the created html as a new page

```
        Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/tmp/")
        Dim strWriter As StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(path & "SomeHtml.html")
        strWriter.Write(htmlString)
        strWriter.Close()
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path & "SomeHtml.html")
```

This works locally but when published on the server it does not open the html page. (Nothing happens when I click on the button that is supposed to trigger the piece of code to create .html and display it. Anybody knows what's going on?

Comment: This is an odd way of doing things, see my answer as to why it may not work, but you should be sure that you *actually* want to do this before you resolve the issue. Why do you need to do Process.Start on an HTML file?

Comment: @NathanKoop You might want to add to your answer that it probably is working, but there isn't much point opening the web page *on the server* and Response.Redirect might be more useful.

Comment: @AndrewMorton very good point! Answer amended

Comment: I don't have to stick with the way I proposed I'm trying to do this. So whatever you think is the better or right way, I will try it. Basically all I want to do is after htmlString is populated with appropriate html code, show that html in a new page.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, 1) a user goes to your webpage and views SomeHtml.html. 2) "Something occurs" and SomeHtml.html is loaded into an htmlString 3) the SomeHtml.html needs to be viewed. Why don't you edit SomeHtml.html? Then the next page refresh will display the correct page? If you want more & better responses you need to provide some more detail as to what the problem you're trying to solve is.

Comment: Nathan Koop! You convinced me that my approach was not good after all. The original problem I was trying to solve that got me here was "How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages" for which I found enough documentation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why I believe this may not work:

1. HTML file doesn't exist on server
2. File Permissions are not set properly

As Andrew Morton properly points out, when this is actually working properly the HTML file will open on the server and will not be displayed to the client. (IE will only be viewable if you RDP into the server)